# Random numbers in string

Tags: python

Why when my string has a small size, the random numbers 0 and 1 are more visible, and when the string has its second (longer) value, it becomes a string of 0?

```
import random
#F = "(~1V3V~5V~7)^(~1V~3V5V~6V~7)"
F = "(~1V3V~5V~7)^(~1V~3V5V~6V~7)^(1V2V~4V~6V7)^(1V2V~4V~5V~7)^(2V5)^(~1V2V3V~5V6V~7)^(2V~3V4V~5V7)"


for x in F:
    if x.isdigit():
        F = F.replace(x, str(random.randint(0, 1)))

print(F)
```

OUTPUT:

```
First string:
run(1): (~1V0V~0V~1)^(~1V~0V0V~0V~1)
run(2): (~0V0V~0V~0)^(~0V~0V0V~0V~0) # all characters are 0?? Why isn't all random numbers value between 0 and 1?
run(3): (~0V1V~0V~1)^(~0V~1V0V~0V~1)

Second string:
run(1): (~0V0V~0V~0)^(~0V~0V0V~0V~0)^(0V0V~0V~0V0)^(0V0V~0V~0V~0)^(0V0)^(~0V0V0V~0V0V~0)^(0V~0V0V~0V0)
run(2): (~0V0V~0V~0)^(~0V~0V0V~0V~0)^(0V0V~0V~0V0)^(0V0V~0V~0V~0)^(0V0)^(~0V0V0V~0V0V~0)^(0V~0V0V~0V0)
run(3): (~0V0V~0V~0)^(~0V~0V0V~0V~0)^(0V0V~0V~0V0)^(0V0V~0V~0V~0)^(0V0)^(~0V0V0V~0V0V~0)^(0V~0V0V~0V0)
```

I want each number in the string to be a random value of 0 or 1. And I don't understand what's wrong.
A little help?

Comment: I am not able to replicate this. I am getting behavior as expected.

Comment: In general, randomness can also produce a string of zeroes, of course. In your specific case though, the first time `x` is "3", it replaces all threes by one or zero, so this increases the likelihood of an all-zero or all-one result. You can do `F.replace(x, str(..), 1)` to only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: @L3viathan I think your comment can be posted as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things:

- It is not good practice to modify the variable you are iterating over inside the loop.
- My interpretation of the problem is: iterate over given string, replace the encountered digits with 0 or 1 at random. F.replace will replacing all instance of the encountered number(x) in the string in above code. Corrct me if i'm wrong.

```
import random
F = "(~1V3V~5V~7)^(~1V~3V5V~6V~7)"

new_F = ''
for x in F:
  if x.isdigit():
    new_F += str(random.randint(0, 1))
  else:
    new_F += x

print(new_F)
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not completely random because you're only really taking into account the last replace by assigning the value back to F, instead you should just use a string join and comprehension to treat each letter individually instead of reassigning the value back to `F`

```
"".join(str(random.randint(0, 1) if x.isdigit() else x for x in F)
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of a problem like this. I will create a new F, where I put the values. And if I wanted to do random numbers, until they all have the value of 1? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @KUWAPT - If you want them to all have the value of 1 then why waste time generating random numbers? Either way that is a different question to the one you're asking here and should raise a new question about it if need be